# How can I ensure that only one instance of any product in woocommerce is sold?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product, inventory-management

I've been looking for an answer to this. Client has a woocommerce shop that will only ever have one of each product. What I need to accomplish is that when a product is added to their cart, the item is unavailable for anyone else to add the same product to a cart. I've tried the old plugin but it breaks portions of the front end, I've tried using several similar solutions I've found here, but nothing seems to do the trick. The plugin also made inventory management on the backend a total nightmare.

So, to walk you through, user A adds product A to cart. User B tries to add this product to cart but woocommerce says its sold out currently to user B. User A can checkout with product A or if user A closes the browser, woocommerce waits one minute and then puts product A back in stock so person B can then add product A to their cart.

I've been searching for this and have come up with nothing from here and some company claiming they can but it's done case by case and they want to handcode it aka very expensive to do.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Just an opinion here so maybe I am wrong, but woo commerce uses stock counts in the backend, so if this is set to 1, then there can only ever be one that can go through the checkout process unless cancelled. 
The functionality to reduce that stock count to 0 whilst a user has that item in their basket (or just viewing the checkout page) is not feasible as they have not purchased, at that stage it is just showing intent to purchase.

As you mentioned, that functionality is possible, it wouldn't be pretty, but possible and not something that is available by default in the plugin. Development of such functionality would be needed, and you're right probably quite expensive for development time.

Comment: You're 100% correct except that if a person adds the product to their cart, and haven't checked out yet, someone else can still buy the item and the first person can still checkout and buy the same product despite there being only a single item.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I would have assumed woocommerce would provide an error on attempt of purchase once checking the item stock level. Either way, this here might be helpful. It allows a users basket items to expire after a configured amount of time. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-cart-stock-reducer/

As i previously mentioned, the issue you have may be an overall problem for WC
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/5966

Comment: That's the plugin I mentioned which broke frontend and made backend inventory management the nightmare

Comment: Ah, then other than suggest contacting a development team to supply such functionality, I cannot help. I hope you get it sorted though!